# Have buttons next to Li on the same vertical level

Tags: html, css

How do I align a button next to all Li's in a list and keep it inline vertically.

This is the problem:
https://gyazo.com/a2deabb59fd68c5d371b0ba67f3aacb6

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart">
            <ul>
                <li>Milk <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Eggs <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Juice <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Pasta <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Water <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Donuts <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you define *same vertical level* ?

Comment: You know have the bins be on the same vertical level. Have them all going down like a line. @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1):

Use Flexbox and give a `margin-left: auto` to the buttons

```css
ul { 
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

li { 
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row; 
   width: calc(100% + 10px);
}

button {
   margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart">
            <ul>
                <li>Milk <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Eggs <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Juice <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Pasta <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Water <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
                <li>Donuts <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do u know how to put more distance between the button and Li tag? Like push the trashbin to the right a bit more.

Comment: Sure, you could use `translateX()`. See the update. Or wrap all the label into a <span> element and give it a padding-right, if you can alter the markup.

Comment: or you can set  a padding-right to the list equals to the space between label and button, which is a better approach than using a transformation

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a table layout:

```css
ul {
  display:table;
}
li {
  display:table-row;
}
li span {
  display:table-cell;
  padding-right:10px; /*to control the distance*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Milk</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Eggs</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Juice</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Pasta</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Water</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Donuts</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or using float if you cannot change the HTML and you need to keep the list style:

```css
ul {
  display: table; /* OR inline-block*/
}

li button {
  float: right;
  margin-left:10px; /* To control the distance */
}
li {
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart">
  <ul>
    <li>Milk <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li>Eggs <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li>Juice <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li>Pasta <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li>Water <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li>Donuts <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE FLEX:**

```css
li {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="shoppingCart">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Milk</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Eggs</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Juice</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Pasta</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Water</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
    <li><span>Donuts</span> <button><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried code as per your requirement. You can check the following code for the same.
I have done it using a table and it is working properly.

```
<ul>
     <table>
         <thead>
             <tr></tr>
             <tr></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>Pasta</td>
                 <td><button class="btn"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Egg</td>
                 <td><button class="btn"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Juice</td>
                 <td><button class="btn"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button></td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Milk</td>
                <td><button class="btn"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</ul>
```